# Max resolution problem

Tags: resolution

My monitor resolution 1600x1200 but when I go to settings and displays the maximal resolution is 1360x768 I tried detect displays but nothing happened

Comment: If it is Nvidia check this:  http://askubuntu.com/questions/664012/second-screen-resolution-nvidia-ubuntu-14-04-lts

Answer (score 0):

Try setting a custom resolution in xorg.conf. You should have one already, and if not, [use this.](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/create-a-xorgconf-file.html) Make sure your SubSection: Display has the right resolution. I had a problem with monitor resolution when I used a DVI to VGA adapter, these adapters can strip out EDID data. The monitor sends the EDID data to the computer to tell it what resolutions it can support.

```
Section "Screen"
    Identifier    "Default Screen"
    Device        "NVIDIA Corporation NV34 [GeForce FX 5200]"
    Monitor        "CM752ET"
    DefaultDepth    16
    SubSection "Display":
        Depth        16
        Modes      "1280x1024" "1024x768"
    EndSubSection
EndSection
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution work for me. I use it on Ubuntu 14.04 and 16.04 and working good!

If you want for example resolution 1290x1080 (Full HD) type in terminal console

```
cvt 1920 1080
```

You will see something like this for output:

```
# 1920x1080 59.96 Hz (CVT 2.07M9) hsync: 67.16 kHz; pclk: 173.00 MHz
Modeline "1920x1080_60.00"  173.00  1920 2048 2248 2576  1080 1083 1088 1120 -hsync +vsync
```

Go to your home folder for example

```
cd /home/mikia
```

Edit or create file .xprofile

```
vi .xprofile
```

Insert folowing text na following previous output from command cvt:

```
xrandr --newmode "1920x1080_60.00"  173.00  1920 2048 2248 2576  1080 1083 1088 1120 -hsync +vsync
xrandr --addmode VGA1 "1920x1080_60.00"
```

Save file, reboot and enjoy in your new resolution :)